# In Python 3, how do I use Regex to replace a string in a file when the replacement string contains unicode characters

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a python script that was written originally for Python 2, that I've had to change for Python 3.

It's purpose is to walk through a directory looking for files of a given type, and replace all lines containing copyright information within those files.

```
import fileinput
import datetime
import sys
import re
import os
year = datetime.datetime.now().year
assemblyInfoPattern = re.compile(r"^\[assembly:\sAssemblyCopyright\(\"Copyright.*\]$")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.') :
    for file in files :
        if file == 'AssemblyInfo.cs' :
            print (f'Checking {root}\\AssemblyInfo.cs')
            for line in fileinput.input(os.path.join(root, file), inplace=True):
                replacementString = '[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2014-' + str(year) + '")]'
                outputLine = assemblyInfoPattern.sub(replacementString, line)
                sys.stdout.write(outputLine)
```

This modified script works fine, **however it's not outputting the unicode copyright symbol © correctly**:

> [assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ɠ2014-2019")]

Comment: What is the encoding of your python script file itself? If I run your code (slimmed down a bit, but using the same functions to manipulate the strings), it works without problems and correctly outputs the copyright symbol. If you're unclear about what this means or how to deal with it, this may also be relevant: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: @Grismar good question, the encoding of the script itself is UTF8.
The target files (AssemblyInfo.cs) are UTF-8 BOM

Comment: Also @Grismar thank you for that link. Is it still relevant for Python 3.7? I notice it references Python 2.3, and my original script executes just fine in Python 2, I just started having issues after I ported it to Python 3.7

Comment: I think it is still relevant, but dealing with encoding is one of the main differences from 2 to 3. A bit more here https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html and note that the default encoding is UTF-8, so your problems shouldn't have to do with what I mentioned. Also note that the `encoding` comment is probably more relevant to your editor - but it could be the cause of things looking fine in the IDE, when they are in fact read differently by the Python interpreter. It looks like this is not the case for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that

```
fileinput.input(file, inplace=True)
```

does not allow you to specify an encoding, and this was the root of my problem, because my target files needed to specify an encoding of utf8.

I was able to rewrite my code in a more verbose manner that allowed me to instead use:

```
with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
```

...which allows me to specify the encoding.

New script:

```
import fileinput
import datetime
import sys
import re
import os
year = str(datetime.datetime.now().year)
assemblyInfoPattern = re.compile(r"^\[assembly:\sAssemblyCopyright\(\"Copyright.*\]$")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.') :
    for file in files :
        if file == 'AssemblyInfo.cs' :
            print (f'Checking {root}\\AssemblyInfo.cs')
            outputFile = ""
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
                for line in f.readlines() :
                    replacementString = '[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2014-' + year + '")]'
                    outputLine = assemblyInfoPattern.sub(replacementString, line)
                    outputFile = outputFile + outputLine
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
                f.write(outputFile)
```

Now my output files contain the correct lines:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2014-2019")]
```

Yay.